# Ignore exceptions in a `for` statement

Tags: python, exception, for-loop

I am enumerating characters of a large character set like this (take GB2312 as an example, but much large in practice):

```
def get_gb2312_characters():
    higher_range = range(0xb0, 0xf7 + 1)
    lower_range = range(0xa1, 0xfe + 1)
    # see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312#Encodings_of_GB2312

    for higher in higher_range:
        for lower in lower_range:
            encoding = (higher << 8) | lower
            yield encoding.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big').decode(encoding='gb2312')

for c in get_gb2312_characters():
    print(c)
```

This won't work because there are some "gaps" (or "garbage" byte combinations) in the code page. When the program tries to get a character from the generator in the last `for` line, it will raise an `UnicodeDecodeError`. The problem is that I cannot use `try...except` to encompass the `for` loop like

```
try:
    for c in gb2312:
        print(c)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass
```

since the loop will terminated immediately if there are exceptions, neither use the pair within the `for` loop like

```
for c in gb2312:
    try:
        print(c)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass
```

because the exception is not raised inside. So any way to get around this? Thank you.

Comment: In which of the three `for` loops does this fail?

Comment: @Floris I've updated my post to eliminate the ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

Try this using this `for` loop inside your function:

```
for higher in higher_range:
    for lower in lower_range:
        encoding = (higher << 8) | lower
        try:
            yield encoding.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big').decode(encoding='gb2312')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
```

The values that fail will be silently ignored, and the generator will return only those that are valid.

Comment: bare `except:` should be used sparingly e.g., why would you want to ignore KeyboardInterrupt here. `except UnicodeDecodeError:` should be used instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian agreed, fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Put the `try except` around the `yield`:

```
try:
    yield encoding.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big').decode(encoding='gb2312')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    # handle exception here
    pass
```